# Is Jell-O flavored plastic?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, polymers, food-chemistry, plastics

Per [this](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-is-jell-o-how-does-i/) article, "Gelatin is a thermoreversible, cold-setting polymer." Further, Jell-O is flavored gelatin.

Is the phrase "thermoreversible, cold-setting polymer" equivalent to the term "plastic?"

Is Jell-O, therefore and despite the unappealing sound of it, flavored plastic?

Comment: Yep, that's a perfectly reasonable description. I would expand to "flavored, edible plastic" but YMMV.

Comment: More of a flavored hydrogel with physical properties that include plasticity. But that's splitting hairs.

Comment: I figured "edible" was inherent to being a foodstuff. I was less certain about the equivalencies of "thermoreversible, cold-setting polymer" and "plastic;" I feel like there might be differences in the terms I wasn't familiar with; I'm not a chemist. I only knew that plastics were polymers, but I didn't know if polymers were plastics. And if it's plastic, why can't I bend it into a position and have it remain that way?

Comment: You kind of do bend it into a position and have it remain that way when you add the plasticizer (water) to the gelatin and cool it in whatever-shaped container you've put it in.

Comment: So the plasticity is more of a temperature-controlled reflow?

Comment: Technically, "plastic" is anything that is moldable, such as clay, as well as organic polymers. Ceramics is also known as a plastic art https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_arts . If you can make a mold of gelatin, it's plastic.

Comment: If someone wants to write this up as an explanatory answer, I'll accept it...